# Parent permalink slug before CPT slug

Tags: wordpress, url, custom-post-type, slug, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm currently busy making a FAQ for my website but i'm struggling with the permalink structure.

I have made a regular page where people can see an overview of the FAQs. I called that page **Klantadvies**.

I installed a Custom Post Type plugin and made a post type called **faq**. I also made a taxonomy which is called **onderwerp**.

Unfortunately the plugin won't allow me to have a page parent in the slug. So i'm wondering if it's possible to have my page slug (klantadvies) in front of the custom post type slug. For example:

http://mypage.com/**klantadvies**/**faq**/**onderwerp**

Thnx in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Rather than using a plugin for your post types and taxonomies, I'd recommend you use these two solutions:

https://generatewp.com/post-type/

https://generatewp.com/taxonomy/

You can use those to create your Post Type and Taxonomies.  Within each of those configs you're allowed to setup the slugs / URL structure that you want to use.

On top of that you're going to need to setup a custom rewrite rule to handle echoing out the values you're looking for on the appropriate layout.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: Thnx Kris! But i'm not quite sure how to setup the URL/slug structure there. What do i fill in at the Post type slug to get it after my page Klantadvies? Same goed for the taxonomy "onderwerp".

Comment: I figured out how to handle the post type and taxonomy, but i'm not sure how to insert a rewrite rule. Could you help me out with that?